# ERRO Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

tenho o seguinte script JS:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#idSelect").change(function(event) {
  var valor = $(this).val();
    //alert(valor);
      $.post( "ajaxSerie.php", { valorInput: valor }, function( data ) {
        var retorno = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(retorno);
        $("#pertence").val(retorno['pertence'])// aqui estou atribuindo um input qualquer o valor retornado do php, o input tera o valor de sala206
        $.each(retorno, function() {
          $('<option>').val(retorno['pertence']).text(retorno['pertence']).appendTo('#teste');
        });
    }); 
});
```

});

no AJAX está assim:

```
  $idValor = $_POST['valorInput']; 
  $result = [
  "pertence" => $idValor
  ];
  echo json_encode($result);
```

quando faço local ele funciona perfeitamente, agora quando passo par ao site no servidor da o seuginte erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, como resolver isso?

Comment: Já tentou dar um `console.log(data)` antes do `JSON.parse()` para ver se o retorno do AJAX é um JSON válido?

Comment: Acabei de fazer, ele retornou um código HTML gigantesco, como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Provavelmente é uma tela de erro do servidor explicando o quê deu errado. Você vai precisar ler esta tela e atualizar a pergunta com as novas informações

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não é erro do php isso, e sim de `CORS` que em linhas gerais significa que você está fazendo uma chamada de um servidor para outro, sem ser dono do outro (estar no mesmo domínio).

Caso você tenha acesso ao outro servidor (o que você está fazendo a chamada), adicione essa diretiva no .htaccess

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```